# Setting ng-class dependant on userID being present in an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat directive iterating over an array. Each iteration is an object containing some data. I am trying to apply a css class to an element in the view contingent on the current user's userID being present in a list of users, in this case `post.likedByUsers`. The object structure is as follows `post.likedByUsers.xpr5s69fhsts.userId`. The `.xpr5s69fhsts` section in my example represents a random generated id as generated in firebase and is the part I need to iterate through to check if the userID matches and if there is a record which does match to then apply the class `postLiked`. Please see below

```
<div ng-repeat = "post in posts">
   <div ng-class = "{postLiked: post.likedByUsers.<need to iterate these>.userId == userID}">
   </div>
</div>
```

Any help on how I could do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use another `ng-repeat` directive to iterate over the firebase generated IDs?

Comment: Is post.likedByUsers  a list of userId ?

Comment: No neda, it is a list of arbitrary $ids userd by firebase the userID is nested in after the arbitrary $id like ... likedByUsers.xpr5s69fhsts.userId.

Comment: So likedByUsers.xpr5s69fhsts is a list of objects

Comment: This is for a like button as you might see in facebook, on rendering the list I would like posts I have previously liked to have the like button highlighted. As such each post has a list of users which have liked it and that is what I am trying to compare my userID to to determine the class of the like button so I can set the color.

Comment: likedByUsers is an object containing xpr5s69fhsts which is also an object which holds the userID. There are many simular objects to xpr5s69fhsts containing other userIDs

Comment: @callmekatootie I only want one instance of that div.

Comment: You mention you wish to iterate over them but then you also mention that you wish to have only one instance of it. Can you do this - update your post with a sample data that is returned from firebase. Keep its structure intact but you can use random properties and values to protect any sensitive info. Once we get an idea of how your data looks like, we can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement, you want to set a specific class if the *current* user has liked the post?

If that is the case, then what you need to do is add a function in your controller on $scope, that checks if the current user has liked the post or not.

```
$scope.hasUserLikedPost = function () {
  // Check your firebase id here and return true/false
}
```

Then, in your HTML just use that function for the ng-class toggle.